# Positioning a div below a div without flex

Tags: html, css

See the following JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/78wrdh3u/4/

Change the content of `div2` from:

```
<div class="div2">
  This is div 2
  <br />
  <br />
  Which has more content
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="div2">
  This is div 2
</div>
```

With height of `div1` and `div2` same, the button (`div4`), gets positioned correctly at the right end below `div2`. However, when the height of `div2` becomes more than `div1`, the button comes in the middle.

How do I avoid this?

The button (`div4`), should always be fixed at the right end below `div2`. I do not want to use `flex` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.

Just add `clear: right` to `div4`.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/78wrdh3u/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

like

```
<div class="div1">
  This is div 1
</div>
<div class="div3">
</div>
<div class="div2">
  This is div 2
  <br />
  <br />
  Which has more content
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div class="div4">
  button
</div>
```